# How can I know if the number given by the user is Integer or double?

Tags: c

We have a question in class: we should get from the user a number (scanf) and we should check if it's an integer or a double number.

If it's a double, we should write "Double" and if it's an integer we should write "Integer"

How can I check if it's an integer or double? Of course we are allowed to use if / else.

Comment: You can't. `int` and `double` are types within C; they're not something the user can type. User input is always characters.

Comment: Read the number as a string, then parse it to see if it contains `.` or `e` or `E`

Comment: Usually, users push keys with numbers embossed on them.  They don't push type declarations.

Comment: You could make assumptions on the kind of intended floating point type by looking at the number of digits entered. @melpomene

Comment: @alk OK, but why? And you're making a lot of assumptions about the input format.

Comment: Why? Because the assignment tells so. @melpomene

Comment: `floor(n) != ceil(n)`

Comment: The assignment is insufficiently defined.

Comment: In terms of what please? @MartinJames

Comment: Inerms of what to do in cases of overlap.

Comment: @alk The assignment doesn't say to distinguish between different floating point types.

Comment: Take the less precise. Sry :-} @MartinJames Update: In terms of after-command digits.

Comment: @melpomene: Correct, so drop the `float` from my answer and return `double` in this case.

Comment: integer @MartinJames

Comment: What is an integer?  Is a string of chars an integer because it looks like one, because it does not contain some set of chars or because it can be represented as an integer type  by the software reading it?

Comment: I'd say in the context of the question: Everything that isn't a floating point number is either an integer or something else. @MartinJames

Comment: @alk You're jumping all over the place. Why are you talking about your answer (below) now? I was replying to your comment.

Comment: It's  questions like this that cause intelligent and knowledgeable students  to fail exams.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to jump around. My last comment referred to how I parsed the assignment. @melpomene

Comment: Ah got you. A `float` can always be (represented by) a `double`. So the assignment/question does no explicitly name it. @melpomene

Comment: If it's not a memory dump, its an integer in hex (assuming 0x to be parsed as in C also). @MartinJames

Comment: I'm actually tempted to upvote this question just for the fun factor:)

Comment: In fact, I have, and retracted my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

- read input as string
- parse the input read
- decide if what has been read could be an integer, (else if float,) else if a double or else something completely different.

---

Update:

The question indeed is not fully defined. That is, it does not specify the possible allowed number of integer bases.

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it, schematically:

1. Read the entire line of input as a string.
2. Trim all leading and trailing whitespace from the string.
3. Use a (standard library) function to parse the string as an integer, that also returns the number of characters successfully parsed.
4. Use a (standard library) function to parse the string as an float, that also returns the number of characters successfully parsed.
5. Compare the two parses. If the integer parse managed the entire string, then it's an integer. Else, if the float managed the entire string, then it's a float. Else, if neither managed, then it's bogus input.

It's important in step 5 to first check for integer and then for float, as an integer input can typically be parsed as a float as well, so integer should take precedence.

Comment: 'Use a (standard library) function to parse the string as an integer', in hex, octal, binary or some other base?

Comment: @MartinJames That of course depends on what you want to all accept as input, but it's not relevant for the higher-level overview. The question indicates `scanf`, in which case these functions should behave like `scanf`.

Comment: @MartinJames: Ok, you are right, in terms that the question does *not* specify the possible allowed integer bases. There could be some .... :-) Missed that.

Comment: I am also assuming that, since it's a question in class, there's quite a bit of implicit assumptions on how simple the solution should be. The assumption is then that it probably doesn't need to be perfect in that it needn't handle multiple bases, and maybe it doesn't even need to handle exponential notation, etc.

Comment: Implicit assumptions cause students to fail exams that they would otherwise have passed easily.

Comment: This schematic overview makes no such assumptions. Once you actually implement it, then you need to make either implicit or explicit assumptions about the type of input supported, in steps 3 and 4. @MartinJames

Answer (score 1):

> ... if the given number by the user is integer or double?
>   ... we should get from the user a number. (scanf) ...

Let us consider various inputs:

1. "123", is certainly an *integer*, yet that would also parse successful a `double`.  Much text that parses as an *integer* would also parse as a `double`.
2. "123.5" would parse as a double, but not an *integer*.
3. "xyz" would fail both.
4. "1e10000" would overflow most `double`, but it is also an *integer*.

Other considerations:

5. *integer* is a math concept and not a C type.
6. Inputs like "123.1" would not likely parse *exactly* into a `double`.
7. Inputs with hundreds of character pose problems.
8. Inputs like "123x" parse initially as an *integer* but fail with the trailing `'x'`.

Proceed with these reasonable assumptions.

A. Input is not too many characters.  *integer* fits in a `long long`.
B. Overflow/underflow/rounding is not an issue.
C. If parses as both, call it an *integer*.
D. Requirements imply using `scanf()` - yuk - much rather use `fgets()`

```
const char *TestInput(void) {
  char buf[100];
  if (sscanf(" %99[^\n]", buf) != 1) 
    return "No interesting input";
  char end;
  long long ll;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%lli %c", &ll, &end) == 1)
    return "Integer";
  double d;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%lf %c", &d, &end) == 1)
    return "double";
  return "neither";
}
```