# How to know if the input the user has given is string or float or integer in C programming

Tags: c, input

User will give only one input only once and output should be printed according to input.

- If user enters a string, it should print "**It is string**".
- If user enters an integer, it should print "**It is Integer**".
- If user enters a float, it should print "**It is Float**".

Comment: It depends on the programmer, how he takes the input!

Comment: Read the data as a string (`fgets()` perhaps — probably, even), and then analyze the string.  You can use `sscanf()` or `strtol()` or `strtod()`, etc, to decide what's in the string.  And you can analyze it different ways because you captured the input.

Comment: No input from `stdin` is `int` or `float`. The input is text, and is interpreted accordingly. Just suppose the input is `01EFh`. Is that a number, or a string?

Comment: You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33601527/) by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) to the question [How can I know if the number given by the user is Integer or double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594935/) which is close to a duplicate and the answer (should) work. Alternatively, it could use `%n` instead of `%c` and check that the end is a null byte (so it would skip leading and trailing blanks).  If neither integer nor float leads to end of string, then the input isn't an integer or float so it must be a string.

Comment: There's also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20069488) by [user694733](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694733/user694733) to the question [How to check if the number is integer or float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068234).  This uses `%n` once — it should do so twice.

Comment: You should also have shown [What  have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Read in a line using `fgets`, then call `sscanf` on the buffer repeatedly, with different format specifiers. Check the return value of each `sscanf` call to see if the format was correct

```
char line[80];
int ival;
float fval;

fgets(line, 80, stdin);

if (sscanf(line, "%d", &ival))
    printf("It is integer\n");
if (sscanf(line, "%f", &fval))
    printf("It is float\n");
else
    printf("It isn't an int nor a float; it is a string\n");
```

The order of the `sscanf` calls matters, by the way. Start off with the most specific format specifier at the top of the `if-else` ladder, and end with the most general.

If you want to handle input that is valid, but has garbage on the end, you will have to use [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), which is more complicated.

Comment: Yes, no, maybe: if the input is `3.14159eggs-per-basket`, then it will report 'it is an integer' (because the first character is an integer), and if it was allowed it would report 'it is a float' (because the first seven characters are a float value), but it should probably report 'it is a string' because the input as a whole is neither an integer nor a float.  I agree with "Use `fgets()`", but the analysis has to be more delicate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it is a matter of specification, not of guessing. What are the valid inputs, and those must checked against (including errors).

Comment: `3.14159eggs-per-basket` would be specified as "<number> [[<opt space>] <opt unit>]".